# Drag and drop multiple items at once to another div using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how to get all the children of a three at once to move them to another three. In my project I have three tbody, where in each of them I have a tr, and several td that are generated according to an ajax request. Each div has a number of elements. The tr 1 has 3 td, the tr 2 has 4 td, and the tr 3 has 5 td. What I want is to move all the tds at once, without selecting them or anything, just click to drag and get them all at once. For example, I click on the td of the three 3 that has 4 td, and when I click on the td, it will take the 4 and make it draggable, so I can drag it to another three.

```js
$('.sortable').sortable({
  revert: true,
  connectWith: ".sortable",
  placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
  
  // Code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody class="sortable">
  <tr>
    <td>Element 1</td>
    <td>Element 2</td>
    <td>Element 3</td>
    <td>Element 4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody class="sortable">
  <tr>
    <td>Element 1</td>
    <td>Element 2</td>
    <td>Element 3</td>
    <td>Element 4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

<tbody class="sortable">
  <tr>
    <td>Element 1</td>
    <td>Element 2</td>
    <td>Element 3</td>
    <td>Element 4</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```